# How To set aria-pressed="true" in Selenium?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

HTML:-

```
<ion-segment-button class="segment-button" role="button" tappable value="sign_in" aria-pressed="false">
```

Selenium Code:-

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("URL");
WebElement Login =driver.findElement(ByClassName.className("segment-button"));
Login.submit();
```

How To set aria-pressed="true" in Selenium??

Comment: your xpth code +"and starts-with(@aria-pressed, 'true')]"

Comment: @Hiten Can you explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to set the attribute of a element in selenium. But we can use the javascript Executor to set attribute of a element as given below.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("URL");
WebElement Login =driver.findElement(ByClassName.className("segment-button"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('aria-pressed',true);",Login);
```

Comment: I Get **Error** in Here i try to slove it .

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is don't. Don't do this unless you really know what you are doing and understand the site. Forcing values on elements using JS shortcuts all the events that the site has to handle this user flow and you could put the page in a bad state. No user is going to run JS on the page to put it in the desired state... your script shouldn't either.

The right way to do this is to figure out how this gets set from a user's perspective. What buttons do I have to push, etc. to get the desired setting? Once you figure that out, write the Selenium code to push those buttons, etc. and you will have the desired result.

Comment: @DebanjanB I know the difference and this is an answer. An answer is not always answering exactly what the OP asked. Sometimes it's offering advice or an alternate approach. See [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Sometimes what OP is trying to do is not a good practice. When this happens, we should offer alternatives and explain why what they are asking is not a good practice.

Comment: You need to start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which clearly says _Ask questions, get answers, no distractions_

Comment: @DebanjanB OK... read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) under 'Answer the question'. `Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative.`, which I did here. Also `The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”`, which I also did here. Also `Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful`, which contradicts what you are stating. You need to stop downvoting my answers as revenge. You are wrong in your understanding of the rules. From now on, I will be reporting you each time you do this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18671902)

Comment: @Dez It does. The answer is don't do what you are suggesting. Instead code what a user would to change the desired attribute. Read above.

Comment: @JeffC, It could be comment instead of post as answer. read  [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)